# Four delegate functions with one user input variable? PANIC MODE

Tags: vb.net, delegates

Well, I'm a little concerned about whoever designed these projects I'm doing, as they keep asking me to do things that I haven't learned.
Anyway, here's what I've been asked to do - make a program that uses various procedures to perform these operations:
1) Print all odd numbers between 1 and N,
2) Print all even numbers between 1 and N,
3) Print all prime numbers between 1 and N, and 
4) Print all numbers divisible by 4 between 1 and N.
The kicker is that N is supposed to be user input.

I have no idea where to go with this. I know how to declare delegates, create Subs, use modulo division, and use a Do Until...
How am I supposed to get one variable in Sub Main to function with all of the other delegates? How do I display prime numbers and only prime numbers between 1 and a number? I think I can handle programming the Subs that go with 1, 2, and 4, but the 3rd one has me completely stumped, and I have absolutely no idea how I'm supposed to connect all of these subs with a single user-input variable.

Can anybody help? Please?

Comment: is `N` supposed to be the same `N` for each procedure?  just write each one as its own procedure, then a control procedure to call them in order passing N (if it is the same), or have each proc get N as input as the first step.  And use a 'FOR' loop. not 'DO'

Comment: Yeah, N is supposed to be the same for each procedure, but... what do you mean "passing N"?

Comment: `Sub PrintPrimes(MaxVal As Integer)` MaxVal is a parameter, which would be the `N` value you collected earlier. to invoke: `PrintPrimes(n)`.  it can be passed to the other procs the same way, then you just do `For n As Integer = 1 To MaxVal` for the loop

Comment: It'll only let me do '(ByVal MaxVal As Integer)', and in any case... if you want me to be completely honest, I have no idea what you're saying. I haven't studied "ByVal"s yet, or anything like them. -_-

Comment: ByVal is fine - there is not a lot of room in comments, so I was being thrifty.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx

Comment: Heh, it's cool... I'm starting to get it. Thanks.

Comment: It sort of sounds like parameter passing might be the point of the assignment, or just making procedures...if N/MaxVal is a "global" variable, you dont have to pass it at all but that is old school.  is this a console app or winforms?

Comment: Console app, and the point is supposed to be making procedures/using delegates.

Comment: ok, out of room here.  Give it a whirl and when you get stuck, you'll get more lots help if the question is succinct and deals with a specific issue, not how to design and develop the entire app.  this is especially true for homework - we dont want the power grid to go down when we are retired because we did your homework for you and you learned zilch.

Comment: it's cool, I just figured out what to do anyway. :P wow...